# How to check regex and only then substitute?

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of similar files that contains

```
<id="1" status="one" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="2" status="three" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="3" status="two" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="4" status="one" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
```

Now I want to go through all files and add `bonus="yes"` for all, except `status="two"`

```
<id="1" status="one" bonus="yes" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="2" status="three" bonus="yes" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="3" status="two" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
<id="4" status="one" bonus="yes" group="first" city="CITY" ... >
```

I have simple regex match, which has three capturing groups

1. full
2. `<id="_" status="__"`
3. `group="___" city="___" ... >`

I know I can add the line somewhere like this

```
with open(fileName) as currentFile:
    content = (currentFile.read())
content = re.sub(regex, f"\\1 {line_to_add} \\2", content)
with open(fileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

How to perform check when `status="two"` to pass them ?

Comment: Instead of reading the entire file into one long string with `currentFile.read()`, I would use `currentFile.readlines()` which will put each line of the file into a separate list item. Then you use a `for` loop to iterate through each line in the file, do a regex test to see if `status="two"`, and if not, then do your `re.sub([...])`

Comment: @ResetACK Hi and thanks, but that's not possible in my case, please read my comment on the answer, can you give another option/workaround please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(fileName) as currentFile:
    content = currentFile.read()

# Here we set up a regex to match your potentially multi-line objects
line_regex = re.compile(r'<id.+[^<]*?\n?>')

# Now we use re.findall to create a list of matched lines
lines = re.findall(line_regex, content)

# Continue as before
status_regex = re.compile(r'status="two"')

for line in content:
    # This will only return `True` if `re.search()` matches
    if not re.search(status_regex, line):
        # Do your re.sub to add 'bonus="yes" to the line

with open(fileName, "w") as f:
    for line in content:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: You don't really need a regex to search for `status="two"`.

Comment: No but to be in-keeping with OP's theme of using regex I figured I'd use it :)

Comment: I would've used readlines() but point is that every entry is not a single line(id=1 can be 5 lines, id=2 - 3 id =3 - 5 and so on, and status="two" can be in any of them) thus I can't specify line count or read line by line and should open full file.  
I thought to change regex to catch everything except status="two" but that would be a temporary solution.  
I want to make command line tool where user can add exceptions and program will not write new "features" to that entries.

Comment: @Arthur See my edited answer - now we read the file in all at once before doing some regex to match multi-line inputs, and then the rest is the same